# Flask wrapper cannot successfully redirect on post requests

Tags: python, ajax, http, post, flask

I have implemented a login_required wrapper for my view functions. The purpose is that in case of a invalid login credendial/timed-out session, wrapper redirects the user to the login page. However, when we send a post request that has a prerequiste  of logged in user, we cannot redirect a timed-out user to the login page. The redirect is not working at all unless we manually refresh the page.

```
def login_required(f):
@wraps(f)
def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
    token = request.cookies.get('token')

    if not token:
        return make_response(redirect('/login'))
    try:
        data = jwt.decode(token, app.config['SECRET_KEY'], algorithms=['HS256'])
    except:
        return make_response(redirect('/login'))

    return f(*args, **kwargs)

return decorated
```

This is the wrapper I coded. Basically we want to send a redirect response when our session token timed-out.

Although, code executes in the correct order, somehow browser not rendering/redirecting to the desired url.

Comment: [Try redirecting with a status code 307](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect) on POST requests.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitive: your variable `token` is equal None.

So, you have to check it: try to change `if not token:` to `if token = None:`